# Theorem about noncontinuable solution of ODE.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $F(t, f(t))$ be defined on the domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^{n+1}}$, where $t\in \mathbb R$ and $f(t)\in \mathbb{R^n}$, and let $F$ be continuous on $\Omega.$

Consider the differential equation
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{df(t)}{dt}=F(t, f(t)) \\
f(a)=A \in \mathbb{R^n}
\end{cases}
$$

**Theorem**

Under the situation above, (i) and (ii) hold.

(i) The **noncontinuable** solution $f(t)$ is defined on the open interval $(\alpha_0, \alpha_1)$.

(ii) $(t, f(t))\in \Omega \ (\alpha_0 <t< \alpha_1)$ and $(t, f(t))\to (\alpha_j, \beta_j)\in \partial \Omega \ (j=0,1)$.$_■$

I don't know what $\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are, and  what $(t, f(t))\to (\alpha_j, \beta_j)\in \partial \Omega \ (j=0,1)$ means. So I cannot understand what this statement means.

I'd like you to explain this theorem and to help me with understanding what this theorem says.

---

The definition of **continuable** and **continuation**.

Let $f$ be a solution of ODE defined on an interval $I$.
If there exist an interval $J$ and a solution $g$ defined on $J$ s.t. $I\subset J$ and $f=g$ on $I$, then $f$ is called **continuable** and $g$ is called a **continuation** of $f$.

Comment: Where is this theorem coming from? Is there a definition elsewhere of the *noncontinuable* word?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I added the concept of **continuable** written on my textbook. And in this textbook, the definition of **noncontinuable** isn't written. I think **noncontinuable** means that $f$ is not continuable.